# reading corresponding columns using python

Tags: python

I have the output in the format :

```
Neighbor         InQ OutQ Up/Down  State
10.230.3.2         0    0 33w5d        1177
10.230.4.2         0    0 33w4d        1175
125.62.173.253     0    0 8w3d         2637
125.62.173.254     0    0 1w3d         2657
```

I want to read the Neighbor(e.g 10.230.3.2) if state is >= 0. Likewise, i want to read all the neighbors where corresponding state column is >=0.

Please suggest me how can I do this?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking for and what format you have this data in but this will print the column `Neighbour` if `State` >=0. You can move this into a list or tuple or dictionary based on your requirements.

EDIT:Assuming the file only has one space per entry and you have formatted it with spaces this will work

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    for row in f:
        data = row.split(" ")
        if data[4]>=0:
            print data[0]
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I have the data in a text file and I tried your code, its not working probably because text file doesn't understand row and column. Any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data_set = [('10.230.3.2', 0, 0, '33w5d', 1177), ('10.230.4.2', 0, 0, '33w5d', 1175), ('125.62.173.253', 0, 0, '8w3d', 2637), ('125.62.173.254', 0, 0, '1w3d', 2657), ('127.0.0.1', 0, 0, '1w0d', -1)]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data = data_set, columns=['Neighbour', 'InQ', 'OutQ', 'Up/Down', 'State'])
>>> df
        Neighbour  InQ  OutQ Up/Down  State
0      10.230.3.2    0     0   33w5d   1177
1      10.230.4.2    0     0   33w5d   1175
2  125.62.173.253    0     0    8w3d   2637
3  125.62.173.254    0     0    1w3d   2657
4       127.0.0.1    0     0    1w0d     -1
>>> df[df.State >=0 ]['Neighbour']
0        10.230.3.2
1        10.230.4.2
2    125.62.173.253
3    125.62.173.254
Name: Neighbour, dtype: object
>>> df[df.State <0 ]['Neighbour']
4    127.0.0.1
Name: Neighbour, dtype: object
```

`pandas` is available via `pip`.

Comment: Hi Nehal,
Can I add the data to df via a text file?
Because I have a lot of data like this and manually feeding the data is not possible.

Comment: @Anjali Sure, yes. Please read: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Comment: @Anjali I read Nehal's documentation and posted a solution similar to his, except it reads the data from raw table format as you asked for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38917796/1636276

Answer (score 0):

Though I think Nehal's answer using pandas is very ideal for this scenario.

You may try this way as well and tweek according to your requirement-

```
>>> for i in range(1, len(t)):
...     temp = t[i].split()
...     if int(temp[4]) >= 0:
...         print temp[0]
...
10.230.3.2
10.230.4.2
125.62.173.253
125.62.173.254
```

**If you wish to write it to a .txt file**

```
t = tuple(open('source_filename', 'r'))
tfile = open('destination_filename', 'a')

for i in range(1, len(t)):
    temp = t[i].split()
    if int(temp[4]) >= 0:
        tfile.write('%s\n' % temp[0])

tfile.close()
```

Comment: Hi PEJK,
My temp is printing ['125.62.173.254', '0', '0', '1w3d', '2657'] for one iteration.
But when I am doing temp[0]/temp[4], etc, its showing me index out of range. I am using Python 2.7, does it has anything to do with it. I am new to Python, so cannot identify the reason for error.

Comment: @Anjali : `temp[0]` and `temp[4]` are strings. You can convert `temp[4]` to `int` or `float`, but not `temp[0]`.

Comment: but when I am writing the contents of temp[0] to another text file, its showing the result as 10.230.3.210.230.4.2125.62.173.253125.62.173.254
How can I possibly ensure separated output as I want to read the output in an excel file.

Comment: @Anjali : you may add a newline character `\n` at the end of print statement. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Pandas before but I read Nehal's linked documentation and based this solution on [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38916031/1636276). This is in response to your comment:

> Can I add the data to df via a text file? Because I have a lot of data like this and manually feeding the data is not possible.

All you have to do to make the code below read from your text file is replace the use of `StringIO` with an actual file handle (e.g. `with open("data_table.txt") as f:...`).

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

DATA = """
Neighbor         InQ OutQ Up/Down  State
10.230.3.2         0    0 33w5d        1177
10.230.4.2         0    0 33w4d        1175
125.62.173.253     0    0 8w3d         2637
125.62.173.254     0    0 1w3d         2657
111.11.111.111     0    0 1w3d         -1
"""


def main():
    data_io = StringIO(DATA)
    table = pd.read_table(data_io, sep='\s+')

    print("Valid neighbours:\n{}\n".format(table[table.State >= 0]['Neighbor']))
    print("Invalid neighbours:\n{}".format(table[table.State < 0]['Neighbor']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
Valid neighbours:
0        10.230.3.2
1        10.230.4.2
2    125.62.173.253
3    125.62.173.254
Name: Neighbor, dtype: object

Invalid neighbours:
4    111.11.111.111
Name: Neighbor, dtype: object
```